# #Floydhub - Can't Close the browser while the code is running

Tags: python, tensorflow, cloud, keras

While i'm running a code script on FloyHub using Jupyter, i can't close the browser tab while it's running. as in the image below

[image]

so, how can i close the browser while the code is running ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, a problem with Jupyter Notebooks itself: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1647. In general, since Notebooks are interactive development environments, its good practice to keep the browser open. Otherwise, it's too easy to forgot that you have a running job and then be charged for the duration it is idle.